# How to replace the same character multiple times?

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

I need to replace a specific character for all elements whose class is the same with jQuery. Consider this html code:

```
<div class="product-name">
   <h1>Apple®</h1>
</div>

<div class="product-name">
   <h2>iPhone®</h2>
</div>

<div class="product-name">
   <h3>iPhone 5S®</h3>
</div>
```

I need to replace all the ® charactesr with superscript tags with this code:

```
$('.product-name').html(
  $('.product-name').html().replace(/®/gi, '<sup>&reg;</sup>')
);
```

However, this code will replace the first occurrence only. For the second and beyond occurrences, it'll replace the whole product names with the first product name including the h1 tags.

How can I replace just the ® characters without changing the other characters and tags?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [callback in `html()`](https://api.jquery.com/html/#html-functionindex--oldhtml) to return the value to each element in the collection

```
$('.product-name').html(function(_, html) {
     return html.replace(/®/gi, '<sup>&reg;</sup>')
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/6mYw7/1/)

Comment: +1 for use of `g` to replace all. Pretty sure the `i` option is redundant on this one :)

Comment: (Ironically, using the callback eliminates the issues on the current input, even without `g` ..)

Comment: @user2864740 - Yes, if there's only one of those characters in each element, the regex wouldn't be needed at all.

Answer (score 1):

Try
`$('.product-name').html().split("®").join('<sup>&reg;</sup>');`

For a more complete answer,

```
var body = $("body").html().split('®').join('<sup>&reg;</sup>');
$("body").html(body);
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cherubdown/akQP3/)

Comment: +1: Clever use of split/join. Be interesting to see how the speed compares to the regex approach.

Comment: This method would need to be inside of an `.each()`

Comment: Yes, it needs to be in an `each` (and actually store the result back in the elements html), but this appears to be just the inner part of the problem. @Christopher Bales: You may want to complete this answer.

Comment: I don't really see how this solves anything, it's exactly the same as the question, except that it uses split and join instead of regex, but `html()` still gets the html for  the first element in the collection only, so it would have the exact same issue, assuming one inserted it in the same outer `html()`, as it stands it does nothing ?

Comment: Clarification added. This actually replaces every one of them in the case that '®' shows up more than once in the tag.

Comment: Now it's working, but not very elegant replacing the entire body.

Comment: @adeneo obviously you'd want to wrap that in whatever div or span the context requires.